# AEM 6.0 Bulk Editor Query Paramaters to get all the "dam:Assets" (images) from /content/dam

Tags: aem, query-builder, gql

I am using AEM 6.0. I need to query and get all the dam:Assets (specifically images) from my repository using bulk editor (/etc/importers/bulkeditor.html)

Please refer the image. I want to know what need to be put in the **Query Parameters** to achieve my results and then export it into ".tsv" file.

Note: **"cq:PrimaryType"** of the image is **"dam:Asset"** and **"jcr:primaryType
"** of the jcr:content node of the image is **"dam:AssetContent"**

[image: Bulk Editor Dashboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really up to you on what parameters you want to use for the search but mostly it will depend on the structure of your DAM as well as the available metadata.

One example of getting images of a certain type would be by using:

**Root path:** /content/dam

**Query parameters:** type:Asset, "/jcr:content/metadata/dam:Fileformat":'JPEG'

This will give you all of the assets with file format of JPEG. There is some documentation you can also use as reference:

- https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2360425
- https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/commons/search/GQL.html

Comment: this was helpful. could you tell me how to modify the above query parameter so as to get all the dam:Assets irrespective of the file formats?

Comment: you'll just need to remove the second query parameter, , "/jcr:content/metadata/dam:Fileformat":'JPEG' and you should get all of them

Comment: I tried that, I put "type:Asset" without the quotes and the result is 0. Is this some bug, because when I put the second parameter, it is returning results.

Comment: Have you tried without the quotes? that should do it